# share dialog image not displaying correct Large Image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

i have a problem with the facebook share dialog display when i share a job ad on my web application. All by facebook demanded Meta Tags for the parts of a contribution are correct also according to the FacebookDebugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/). The image image itself is displayed correctly in the debugger with the format 1200x630 how facebook allow it.

Nevertheless, the sharing of a job ad does not work properly on my side. The image gets cropped in the popup and the post on facebook is cropped too [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5OUC.png). Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

Thanks for the replies .

Comment: Try specifying the image dimensions as well, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching If that doesn’t help (what image format Facebook displays depends on multiple factors, and might even differ for one and the same post, depending on where it is shown and to whom), you could try and specify a second image (see http://ogp.me/#array), in square format. That way, when facebook chooses to display a square image, at least you might have control over what exactly gets shown.

Comment: @CBroe Thank You for you're Reply. I tried to specify multiple images but it doesnt work. The Object Debugger recognizes both images. But if i share the page in my webapplication second image in square format wont be displayed See here: http://imgur.com/0KYENAa,9qSCcVh#1. Do you have any ideas?